# How to get TwinCAT HMI after accidently publishing a wrong one on a secondary system

Tags: dashboard, plc, twincat

I have a simulator with a touchscreen which showed the information about the sensor status and actuator status along with some other information, I accidently published an empty HMI on the screen while I was learning how to make HMI. Is there a way to get back the initial HMI

[BEFORE, I need this back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgImU.png)
[AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMOwA.png)

Please note the PC where HMI is deployed is a licensed PC and contains the files of HMI content but I am not able to access them on that PC.